# Does each microservice's local transaction affect database immediately in saga pattern?

Tags: microservices, distributed-transactions, saga

is each microservice's local transaction persistent in Saga pattern. For example, microservice A completed its transaction and sent an event to microservice B and are microservice A's operations affect database immediately which results with inconsistent state or do they affect after last microservice's OK event?

Answer (score 0):

The point of the Saga pattern is to work with no blocking. If the state of the  local transaction of A would be driven by the last microservice outcome (i.e. by B) then the A would be waiting for the result of B. Then the A would be blocked in processing in some way.

For the saga pattern the local transaction is applied immediately when the microservice finishes its work. If failure happens the saga then ensures the A is informed about that outcome and A is responsible to compensate the work being done. That could be for example deleting the persistent record. The microservice A could for example persist the outcome of the local transaction with some flag (like "saga in progress") and does not consider such item until the saga is finished as whole (then switching the flag to something like "finished").